# How to resolve a hotkey conflict?

Tags: scripting, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

I bound <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to an action, for example:

```
!Space::Send, Foo
```

Now how to trigger the original <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>'s action (as shown in the image below) through code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinguish between user keystrokes and "artificial" ones you have to make use of keyboard hooks.

These hooks are typically setup automatically. (Although there's the possibility of manual changes with [#InstallKeybdHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm))

But even if available they are not always in use. To force them you can use [#UseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) or the [modifier symbol](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) "$" in front of hotkey definitions.

An example related to your question:

```
$!Space:: MsgBox, Action configured with hook.
F2:: Send, !{Space} ; This can still trigger the old behavior.
```

A different approach would be temporarily to turn off your hotkey through the [Hotkey command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm).